# How to write to H2 trace file in case of exception

Tags: java, sql, exception, h2, trace

Here is a simple ALIAS routine that runs an XPATH against an XML fragment.

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS XMLQUERY;
CREATE ALIAS XMLQUERY AS $$
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
@CODE
String xmlquery(String xml, String xpath_expr) {
    try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    java.io.InputStream ins = new java.io.StringBufferInputStream(xml);
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(ins);
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpath_expr);
    return (String)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
$$
```

The code works fine, returning a `null` value when the XML cannot be parsed. But `test.trace.db` does not contain the stack trace.

How do I modify this code to log the stack trace?

Comment: Maybe you should start by opening a database connection?

Comment: This is a `User-defined function` that is being called inline from a `SELECT` statement. It does not need to access the SQL engine.